# Is it possible to embed a facebook feed dialog on a web page?

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to embed the facebook feed dialog on a page rather than have it popup overlayed on the page.

I've followed the instructions here and get it to popup, but dont' know if it's even possible to have it embedded on the page. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `display` parameter in [Common Dialog Parameters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display).

According to that you can show a dialog as a page,iframe,popup.
Using an iframe could be useful in your case, for which you will need a valid access_token.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I just wrote up how to do this along with a workaround for specifying the recipient here: [Letting user specify recipients within Feed Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260166/letting-user-specify-recipients-within-feed-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot embed it to the page.

basically it is either popup or lightbox.

see the link provided by Dhiraj Bodicherla