# Posting a message on facebook using django-facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-facebook

I've tried to find the answer but I couldn't find any topic that could answer my question.
I just added `django-facebook` to my project and I'm trying to post on a Facebook's user.

Here is the situation. Person A logs in to the system then he wants to post a message on Person B. They both are registered to the system and already gave `permissions(publish_actions,publish_stream)` I'm just wondering what command do I need to use?
I've tried

```
facebook = OpenFacebook(access_token)
facebook.set('me/feed', message='check out fashiolista') 
#this is like posting a message on A's facebook. So If I use commend's command, can A post his message on B facebook?
facebook.set('B/commends', message='check out fashiolista')?
```

Can someone please explain how to use the command `commends`?
Thanks you

Comment: What you want is to post a message from user A to user B wall?

Comment: Yes that was I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Person A logs in to the system then he wants to post a message on Person B.

You can **not** post to other user's wall with Graph API. It has been deprecated in Feb 2013. Use have to use [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) instead to post on other user's wall.

It has been discussed before: [How to post on a friend's Timeline after the February 2013 migration takes effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190877/how-to-post-on-a-friends-timeline-after-the-february-2013-migration-takes-effec)