# Post content on friend facebook's wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am implementing a functionality to post content on my friend facebook wall with the help of Graph API.
But I am getting this error:

> OAuthException: (#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application

So I want to know whether this functionality is removed by facebook or this functionality is possible using open graph or something else API.

Please provide me suggesstions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting to friends wall is deprecated now. The same has been discussed here before: [How to post on a friend's Timeline after the February 2013 migration takes effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190877/how-to-post-on-a-friends-timeline-after-the-february-2013-migration-takes-effec)

The Open Graph wont help too. The posting to friends wall is only and only possible with [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) now. Or, you can tag friends in a post with [Open Graph - Mention Tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/).

Comment: thanks sahil for your post. Yes, it helps me a lot :)