# Posting notification to facebook wall of friend titanium android

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, titanium

Hi I am working in titanium. I am facing a strange issue. I try to publish a message on my friends wall through my titnaium app it is working very well over iPod,iPhone and iPad but it does not work on Android devices. It throws an error

```
(#200) feed story publishing is disabled for this application.
```

Kindly suggess something I searched over google but never got any solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing on the friends wall was deprecated Feb 2013 onwards.

This is now possible ONLY using the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog).

See here for the complete discussion: [How to post on a friend's Timeline after the February 2013 migration takes effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190877/how-to-post-on-a-friends-timeline-after-the-february-2013-migration-takes-effec)

Comment: I think this is not the issue cause It is working fine on iOS but failed in android :(

Comment: Its working man. Request with graph path fiendId+'feed/' It is working on iOS like a charm.