# Script (PHP/JAVA) that posts on friend's wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got a trouble. I searched whole stackoverflow and still cannot find the answer.

I read, that there were some changes with facebook scripts that you can't post to other users walls (i got the simple script and still got the message "(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application".

I got my own app, got the secret etc.

I am trying to do the button, that when user on my site (which is connected with facebook to it) clicks on it, there pops up a form with information to fill:

1. To which friend we will post on the wall (list of friends)
2. Message (to fill)
3. Link (link must be added from me in the script).

If You can help me, i will be thankful.

I looked in the whole stackoverflow, tried many scripts, phpsdk etc. Many scripts worked, but only for posting on my own wall + i cant include this friends list to it.

If you got some ready scripts, i will be thankful too.

Comment: Thu shalt not code for the dark and evil facebook.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?  SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2EhWVKE9

Comment: or http://pastebin.com/znJARLMu this

Answer (score 0):

Posting on the friends wall using Graph API is deprecated now. See this discussion: [How to post on a friend's Timeline after the February 2013 migration takes effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190877/how-to-post-on-a-friends-timeline-after-the-february-2013-migration-takes-effec)

Only possible way to post on a friends wall- [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog)

Comment: yes all is possible use this https://www.dropbox.com/s/2t3u2a85n4qv645/facebook%20auto%20like.txt?dl=0 file and do the same from console tab

Comment: Even you can post by php scrpit https://www.dropbox.com/s/2t3u2a85n4qv645/facebook%20auto%20like.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invite them then copy the js code from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7b4s53dzwevofah/autolike.txt?dl=0) and open your facebook page to invite your friends and pest this in console.

to open console got to browser setting >> more tool >> Developer tool >> and the last is console tab.

Pest the code and press Enter...

All Friends will invited to like the page...

[Copy the script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7b4s53dzwevofah/autolike.txt?dl=0)