# iOS - Facebook App Test User - Publish Action

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish-actions

As according to new facebook policies, an App has to be reviewed and approved by Facebook in order to use **Taggable Friends** and `publish_actions` features.

I have created Test Users with Facebook App to provide the facebook review team with but when I publish it throws following error:

> "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".

It is all good with my real account which I have added as Developer in the app and the Admin account as well.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was actually a bug from Facebook end, it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that- *I have created Test Users with Facebook App to provide the facebook review team with but when I publish it throws.....* — what was the response from facebook? Did they approved your submission?

Until and unless facebook approves your submission **only** the admins/developers and testers aan test the publishing feature from your app. And if you are confused with the submission process, check out [**this link**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login), they have explained the login review in detail.

**Edit:**

If you are trying to post a feed on the friend's wall- this is not allowed. Facebook deprecated this functionality long ago. You can check out this discussion: [How to post on a friend's Timeline after the February 2013 migration takes effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190877/how-to-post-on-a-friends-timeline-after-the-february-2013-migration-takes-effec)

Comment: "Until and unless facebook approves your submission only the admins/developers and testers aan test the publishing feature from your app" - This is what I have done, I am doing it with test users, and publish_actions is not working, It works ok for Administrator and Developer

Comment: Well, it works with the test users also. You must be doing something wrong! May be you can explain your steps here so that we may help you with this

Comment: I have added test users for my app. I am fetching friends using taggable_friends permission, and post a feed with a tag id of selected friend, it throws the authorization error

Comment: Publishing on the friends wall is not allowed!

Comment: I am not publishing on Friend's wall, I am tagging a friend in my post. using the action tagging feature.

Comment: You tagging a friend or a test user?

Comment: Tagging a test user from a test user account (these are linked as friends in app settings)